# EMFILE: too many open files, open 'C/...../metro-cache//dd.....'

Tags: react-native, microsoft-metro, nvm

I was running my react native app in node -v 18.17.0 but in between I accidently changed my node version to 16 for some other project, now it says [this is showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vYOF.jpg)

Android Bundling failed 29415ms
Android ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░ 87.0% ( 2010/12763)D:\placeholder\App-Dev\yw-app-master-phase2\nodules\metro-cache\sr c\Cache.js:84
throw err;
^

[Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'C:\placeholder\placeholder\placeholder\Local\Temp\metro-cache\86\f97843613480d5d48f7effdb7c7f01f06808f6c6d6c7a0e435fd8f740293d697c9d8c1'] {
err no: -4066,
code: 'EMFILE',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\placeholder\placeholder\placeholder\Local\Temp\metro-cache\86\f97843613480d5d48f7effdb7c7f01f06808f6c6d6c7a0e435fd8f740293d697c9d8c1'
}

Node.js v18.17.0

I have tried going back to node version 18.17.0 but it isn't working, I have already deleted all my node modules and ran npm i but still didn't work.